# Angular - Get Input value from Component to Service

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to make a login page that contains an APIkey that the user already owns.

On the Login page, the user enters his key and accesses the site. I don't know how to import the input value in service auth.

auth.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  APIkey = `99535281c5b2c837479f8f91f82d88b3a3698072d1f8557b437` //this is the api I want to import from the input 
  signUpURL = `https://gorest.co.in/public/v2/users?access-token=${this.APIkey}`
  signInURL = `https://gorest.co.in/public/v2/users?access-token=${this.APIkey}`


  isLoggedIn = false; 


  isAuthenticated(){
    return this.isLoggedIn 
  }

  signUp(email: string, name: string, gender: string, status: string){
  return this.http.post(this.signUpURL,{email: email, name: name, gender: gender, status: status, returnSecureToken: true})
  }

  signIn(accesstoken: string){
    return this.http.post(this.signInURL,{accesstoken: accesstoken, returnSecureToken: true})
    }

}
```

signin.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { AuthService } from '../auth/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-signin',
  templateUrl: './signin.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./signin.component.css']
})
export class SigninComponent {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService){}
  
   //this is the function that the api gets from the input
   onSubmit(accesstoken: string) {
  console.log(accesstoken)
}
}
```

signin.component.html

```
<h1>Login</h1>
<!-- <form #signinForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(signinForm)"> -->
  <form #signinForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(accesstoken.value)">

 <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Access Token</mat-label>
  <input matInput type="text" name="accesstoken" #accesstoken ngModel required>
 </mat-form-field>


 <button mat-raised-button color="primary" type="submit" [disabled]="!signinForm.valid">Send</button>
</form>
```

In short, I would like the APIkey variable present in auth.service.ts to be updated with the api entered by the user in the input. Can someone help me?

Comment: Does `console.log(accesstoken)` in the `onSubmit()`-method show the correct value or just always `undefined`?

Comment: Yes, It does. It shows the correct token.

Comment: Can't you just say `this.authService.APIkey = accesstoken` inside the `onSubmit()` method? Or do you first want to call the `signIn()`-method in the service and the assign the return-value to the `APIkey`-variable ?

Comment: I would simply like the token to be replaced in the auth.service.ts with the one the user enters during login. How do I call the value of onSubmit(accesstoken: string) {
  this.authService.APIkey = accesstoken;} in the auth. service.ts? Forgive me, I don't know Angular well, I'm learning now!

Comment: When you write `onSubmit(accesstoken: string) { this.authService.APIkey = accesstoken;}` then the token in auth.service.ts will be replaced as soon as the user clicks the 'submit'-button.

Comment: onSubmit(form: NgForm){
   const accesstoken = form.value.accesstoken
   this.authService.signIn(accesstoken).subscribe(data =>{console.log(data)})
   form.reset()
  }

This is the method I created to send data, where should I put "this.authService.APIkey = accesstoken"? For now, it only sends the data with the APIkey that I wrote in the auth.service.ts

Comment: Are `accesstoken` and `APIkey` really the same thing? And what do you want to do with `data` after it was returned from `signIn()` ?

Comment: Yes `accesstoken` and `APIkey` are the same thing. When I got the data I would like it to return the json of that url.

Comment: Give me some minutes. I will write a sample code and post it as an 'answer' so we can discuss about it. Actually I will also suggest some changes in your HTML.

Comment: Can you check again now

Comment: Btw: I recommend to initiate the property `APIkey` with an empty string and then just assign the token the user entered via form. It's not considered good practise to have hardcoded sensitive data in your frontend code (such as api-keys).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to make changes in all parts of your code, e.g. I turned your form into a proper reactive form. Yet the biggest issue I found was in the `Auth-Service`:

signInURL = `https://gorest.co.in/public/v2/users?access-token=${this.APIkey}`;

Inside this string `this.APIkey` will be assigned once and never gets updated again! That's why in my own code the final request-url gets assembled inside `signUp()` resp. `signIn()`.

The relevant part of the **SignIn-Component TS**:

```
form: FormGroup;

constructor(private authService: AuthService) {
    // Initialize the form
    this.form = new FormGroup({
        accesstoken: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
    });
}

onSubmit() {
    console.log('Access-token entered by the user:', this.form.value.accesstoken);
    // Store API-Key entered by user to Auth-Service:
    this.authService.APIkey = this.form.value.accesstoken;
    // Reset form-inputs:
    this.form.reset();
    // Send API-Key entered by user to backend:
    this.authService.signIn(this.authService.APIkey).subscribe(
        data => {
            console.log('Data Returned from backend:', data);

            // TODO: Do something with the data returned from the backend               
        }
    );      
}
```

The **SignIn-Component HTML**:

```
<h1>Login</h1>
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-label>Access Token</mat-label>
      <input matInput type="text" formControlName="accesstoken" required>
    </mat-form-field>
    <button mat-raised-button type="submit" [disabled]="form.invalid">Submit</button>
</form>
```

The **Auth-Service**:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

    // Important!
    // You basically shouldn't store a working default API-Key in your frontend!
    APIkey = '99535281c5b2c837479f8f91f82d88b3a3698072d1f8557b437';
    signUpURL = 'https://gorest.co.in/public/v2/users?access-token=';
    signInURL = 'https://gorest.co.in/public/v2/users?access-token=';
  
    isLoggedIn = false; 

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  
    isAuthenticated(){
        return this.isLoggedIn 
    }
  
    signUp(email: string, name: string, gender: string, status: string){
        // Assemble the final url here:
        const signUpUrl = this.signUpURL + this.APIkey;
        return this.http.post(signUpUrl,{email: email, name: name, gender: gender, status: status, returnSecureToken: true});
    }
  
    signIn(accesstoken: string){
        // Assemble the final url here:
        const signInUrl = this.signInURL + this.APIkey;
        return this.http.post(signInUrl,{accesstoken: accesstoken, returnSecureToken: true});
    }
}
```

Comment: It works properly! Thanks so much for your time. Now everything is clearer to me!

Comment: You are welcome. Happy coding and a happy new year :-)